# How to set custom width and height of jssor slider

Tags: jquery, slider, width, jssor

Using `$ScaleWidth` or `$ScaleHeight`, I could set either **Width** or **Height** of a jssor slider which maintains aspect ratio:

**jQuery:**

```
var jssor_slider1 =  new $JssorSlider$('slider1')

jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(500);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider1" style="position:relative;top:0px;left:0px; width:600px;height:300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" ....
```

But I need to set custom width and height; not like aspect ratio as above code.

Suppose, here initial width = 600px and height = 300px.

Can I update width to **1200px** and height to **400px** ?

Comment: By scaling jssor slider, it will always keep aspect ratio. You can use either `$ScaleWidth` or `$ScaleHeight` to scale jssor slider, and finally, the aspect will keep unchanged. If you scale width to `1200px`, the height will be `600px`.

Comment: As workaround, you can put jssor slider into a container. You can scale the container and the aspect ratio is totally up to you.

Comment: @jssor So there is no option in API to reset either width or height  after  creating slider . Right? By  the way, Thanks for valuable response :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody answered, **@jssor**'s comments on my question are the current answer:

> By scaling jssor slider, it will always keep aspect ratio. You can use
>   either `$ScaleWidth` or `$ScaleHeight` to scale jssor slider, and finally,
>   the aspect will keep unchanged. If you scale width to 1200px, the
>   height will be 600px.
>
> As workaround, you can put jssor slider into a container. You can
>   scale the container and the aspect ratio is totally up to you. – **jssor**

Comment: Please try the new api `$ScaleSize` method. `$ScaleSize(1200, 400)`, it will keep aspect ratio, some area will bleed outside.

Comment: Is there any option to fit size ignoring aspect ratio in the new API?

Comment: No such feature available, you can apply custom style on the slider element as workaround `style="transform: scaleX(0.6);scaleY(1);`